# Android Auto app doesn't work for reviewer, but works for us

Tags: android, android-auto

I can't get my app through the revieew process. They have the following issue:

> Looking at your updated APKs from earlier today, we found the same issues persist. Specifically, we can't hear any audio while the app appears to be playing music (the scrubber bar moves, but no audio is heard)
>
> The only time music is heard, is when we tap on the microphone button to initiate voice commands. The system can't hear our request as audio is playing when it should be stopped and listening. Lastly, when we exit the Voice Command prompt, the music stops again and we hear nothing in normal mode.
>
> I hope this helps explain the behavior that we're seeing. Please work to correct this behavior in a new APK and upload into the Developer Console. We're happy to take a look.

But it works correctly for me. I've presented the app to my bosses, colleagues and friends and it always worked as expected. The music plays from auto (not phone), it pauses on voice input and ducks on eg. navigation cues.

Any idea what might be wrong?

I'm using Desktop Head Unit emulator, Android Auto 2.0 app and Nexus 5X with Android 7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found it!

1. Start media playback in the app
2. Start DHU, the playback should pause
3. When you try to play media through DHU, silence, but it seems it should be playing. Logcat seems ok, throbber moves as it's playing.

The problem was with audio focus handling.

I acquired focus on `MediaBrowswer` creation and abandoned it on destruction. Wrong! You should acquire focus on playback start and abandon it on pause or stop.

Answer (score 2):

This happens sometimes on my car as well.
Probably due to Bluetooth/USB audio switch.
Test your app with no BT connection (USB audio).
If it works, submit it again and tell the reviewet to try switching off BT.

Comment: I'm testing it with BT disabled and it works. I'll try to find someone with real Android Auto in my city...

Comment: Hi Pitel. Are you just developing an apk? I am really sick with chronic sinusitis but I can take a minute to test it if you want. My email is rsavutiu@gmail.com. You can sign the apk or something before sending it to make sure it's obfuscated.

Comment: @Pitel let me know if you need help

Comment: @We should kindly tell Google testers you're not responsible for the Bluetooth stacks inconsistencies, Bluetooth/USB switch bugs in Android auto, and so on. They should test your app only.